# Swap/order values by row

Tags: python, numpy, row

I have (N,2) numpy array :

```
 [3,5]
 [4,2]
 [1,6]
 [5,4]
 .....
```

I want to swap the values on every row so that the bigger value is FIRST

```
 [5,3]
 [4,2]
 [6,1]
 [5,4]
 .....
```

Comment: Just sort the array with `arr.sort()` and view it with `arr[:, ::-1]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
array.sort()
array = array[:, ::-1]
```

if `array` is your numpy array

Comment: If you think this is the solution to your question, please mark it as the best answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
ori_arr = np.array([[3, 5], [4, 2], [1, 6], [5, 4]])
print('''{}
The original array:
{}
'''.format("="*20, ori_arr))
# Straight forward way
for i in range(len(ori_arr)):
    ori_arr[i] = sorted(ori_arr[i], reverse=True)
print('''{}
The swapped array:
{}
'''.format("="*20, ori_arr))
```

The results are:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Below is the answer i tried and i  got the output , there could be efficient methods as well.

```
import numpy as np
    
    x=np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[7,6]])
    
    for i  in x :
        if i[0] >= i[1]:
        else:
            a= i[0]
            i[0]= i[1]
            i[1]= a
    
    print(x)
```

Comment: what `if i[0] >= i[1]` is true. above code will not work unless you go with `continue` if condition is true.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).